# C++ , using g++ to compile works fine if new file else got issues

Tags: c++

I got this issue is after i run countryServer in background and then i kill it. I try recompile a new version and this is what i get

```
root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/shell_assignment/shell_assn2# g++ -o countryServer CountryServer.cpp
root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/shell_assignment/shell_assn2# ./countryServer &
[1] 3097
root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/shell_assignment/shell_assn2# 
Running server program 'css' ...... 

Country Directory server started

root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/shell_assignment/shell_assn2# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2993 pts/3    00:00:00 su
 3001 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
 3097 pts/3    00:00:00 countryServer
 3098 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/shell_assignment/shell_assn2# kill 3097
[1]+  Terminated              ./countryServer
root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/shell_assignment/shell_assn2# g++ -o countryServer CountryServer.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file countryServer: No such device or address
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/shell_assignment/shell_assn2# ls -l
total 60
-rw-r--r-- 1 baoky baoky 19545 Aug  2 10:33 Countries.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  14756 Aug  4 03:17 countryClient
-rw-r--r-- 1 baoky baoky  3514 Aug  4 03:19 CountryClient.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 baoky baoky  4740 Aug  4  2012 CountryData.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 baoky baoky  2022 Aug  2 10:33 CountryData.h
srwxr-xr-x 1 root  root      0 Aug  4 03:29 countryServer
-rw-r--r-- 1 baoky baoky  7762 Aug  4 03:18 CountryServer.cpp
```

I get an error that return me this 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file countryServer: No such device or address
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I can fix it if i do rm -rf countryServer

but how do i fix it so it can overwrite the old countryServer ( after i kill its process and recompile it)

Answer (score 4):

Your `countryServer` program appears to be creating a socket file called `countryServer` in the current directory, overwriting itself in the process.

Delete that socket file before compiling your code, or better: change your code so that it doesn't overwrite its own executable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Change the code so that it uses another socket file name. Or change your executable name if the socket file name is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

**c**ountryServer.cpp and **C**ountryServer.cpp are different files on a Linux/Unix system.

Answer (score 1):

File paths are case sensitive in linux.

countryServer.cpp and CountryServer.cpp are not the same path.